# 2002 Dodge Grand Caravan

Tags: dodge, grand-caravan

My 2002 Dodge Grand Caravan won’t crank or start, I took out the old bcm but before I did I tried the key test and I received no data, but when I put a used one in it I got the key test results when I tried the test, I was wondering could I get the used one programmed and do you think it would be the solution for my problem

Comment: Welcome to the site ;).